# Delphi XE7 TBitBtn Image wrong Displayed at run time

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

I have a project developed with Delphi 7 and VCL, that compiles and works with the new Delphi XE7 without any modification, the only issue that I'm experiencing is that the Glyph image of the TBitBtn is wrong displayed(*as you can see the color and the position are not the same*) at run time despite is well displayed at design time .

**Design Time** :

[image: TBitBtn Image Design Time]

**RunTime** :

[image: tBitBtn Image Run Time]

What can cause the problem ?

**NOTE**

With the old Delphi 7 I don't have this issue : the image is correctly displayed both at design and run time .

Following the first 3 lines of the Glyph data in the dfm :

```
Glyph.Data = {
  36050000424D3605000000000000360400002800000010000000100000000100
  080000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000164900001C
  4D0000275700003C7100003D6E00004483000046760000467B0000548C00005B
  ...
```

that it is the same in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE7.

If I click on the Glyph property of TBitBtn I can see the image(the wrong one) in the dialog and if I confirm with OK, the IDE changes the Glyph property in the DFM files in this way(diff output) :

```
     Glyph.Data = {
-      36340000424D3638000000000000360800002800000040000000400000000100
-      1800000000000030000000000000000000000001000000000000724242007B47
-      47007D4849007E4C4B00804C4C0081524F008155500083535200845754008458
-      56008459590085525200855B5700875D58008B6260008B6361008B6362008C65
-      63008C6664008D615C008D6665008D6766008E5A5A008F696800906B6A00916C
-      6B00935F5F00936F6E0094616100946F6F00957170009773730097747400986A
-      6600997777009C7B7B009E7D7D009F6B6B00A06C6C00A1818100A26E6E00A37B
-      7400A3817600A4707000A6727200A67C7600A6867A00A7737300A7877B00A983
-      7B00AA8E8E00AB8C7F00AC8A7F00AC8F8F00AE918300AE939300AF959500B190
-      8400B1958700B2999900B37F7F00B49B9B00B79F9F00B8848400B89FA000BA86
-      8600BB878700BBA5A500BC888800BE8A8A00C08B8B00C18D8D00C1A89700C2AD
-      AD00C38F8F00C4A69800C5919100C7929200C8939300C9949400CA959500CB95
-      9600CB969600CCA79D00CDA49D00CF999A00CFBBA700D09D9C00D0BCA700D0BC
-      A800D0BDA900D19C9C00D1BDA900D29F9E00D39E9E00D3AAA300D49F9F00D4B2
-      A700D4C1AC00D4C1AD00D4C2AD00D4C5C500D6ABA500D6C8C800D7ADA700D7C5
-      B000D8AFA800D8C7B000D8C7B100D8CACB00D9B1A900D9BEAE00DAB2AA00DAB3
-      AA00DAB3AB00DACAB300DACECE00DBA6A600DBB4AB00DBB4AC00DBB5AC00DBB6
-      AC00DBC1B000DBCBB400DBCCB400DCB6AC00DCB6AD00DCCCB400DDB7AE00DDB8
-      AE00DDCDB600DEADAB00DEBAAF00DEBBB000DED4D400DFBCB100DFBDB100DFBD
-      B200DFBEB200DFD0B900E0ADAC00E0B4AE00E0BDB200E0BEB200E0BFB300E0D2
-      BA00E1ADAD00E1C0B400E1C1B400E1D1BA00E2BAB200E2C3B500E3C4B600E3C5
-      B700E3C7B700E4C5B700E4C7B700E4C7B800E4C8B800E4C9B900E5C9B900E5CA
-      B900E5CABA00E5CBBA00E6CCBC00E6DDDD00E7CEBD00E7D7C000E8B8B500E8B9
-      B600E8BAB600E8C3B900E8CFBD00E8CFBE00E8D0BE00E8D0BF00E8D1BF00E9C7
-      BB00E9D1BF00E9D2BF00E9D2C000E9D3C000EAC7BC00EBD5C200ECB9B800ECCE
-      BF00ECD4C200ECD7C300ECD8C300ECD8C400ECD9C400ECE6E600EDD9C400EDD9
-      C500EDDAC500EDDBC500EED3C300EEDBC700EEDCC700EEDDC800EFCCC100EFDD
-      C800F0BEBC00F0DFC900F0E0CA00F0E1CA00F0E1CB00F1E1CB00F1E2CB00F1E2
-      CC00F1E3CC00F1EDED00F2C4C100F2C9C200F2DDCA00F2E3CC00F2E4CC00F2E4
-      CD00F2E5CD00F2EDEE00F3E5CD00F3E5CE00F3E6CE00F3EFEF00F4F0F000F4F0
-      F100F5E5CF00F5F2F200F6EBD200F6ECD300F6F3F400F7ECD300F7EDD300F7ED
-      D400F7EED400F8EDD400F8EED400F8EED500F8EFD500F8F0D500F8F6F600F9EF
-      D500F9F0D600F9F1D600F9F1D700F9F7F700FAF2D700FAF8F800FAF9F900FBF4
-      D900FBF9F900FBFAFA00FCFBFB00FDFDFD00FEFEFE00FFFFFF00FFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFDFCFCD3C5C5C7B5B5D7CBCBE4DC
-      DCEFEAEAF7F5F5FDFCFCFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
+      36300000424D3634000000000000360400002800000040000000400000000100
+      1800000000000030000000000000000000000001000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFF
       FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
       FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
       FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@@ -469,7 +403,43 @@ object Form1: TForm1
       FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
       FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
       FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}
+      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}
```

At [this link](http://ipaste.org/4Rj) there is the complete DFM file that present the problem .

Comment: What type of image is that? Based on quick observation it seems that some data corruption happens at runtime or data isn't loaded properly. If you look at the picture it seems that color chanels might have been scrambled. Green color seems to be replaced with blue, blue with red as if the color channels would be shifted by one byte. Image position offset might also be the result of this data damage or incorect data processing as if file header wasn't parsed properly and the program treats it as image data perhaps.

Comment: Please show the image as the original .bmp you loaded into the BitBtn in D7. Also copy from the .dfm (both D7 and XE7) the three first lines of hex values after `Glyph.Data = {`

Comment: I think the original image was a PNG file(maybe converted in BMP), I can't say for sure because I've inherited the project from a previous developer and I don't have the original imported image file ... Anyway I've updated the question with some useful information . Thanks.

Comment: As you see below I analysed the new info you gave above, and it just doesn't make sense. I attached an image for you to try with, how does it work for you? BTW, are you using TActions in your UI?

Comment: Update the post with the link of the complete DFM file. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to enter another answer instead of editing the previous, because the first answer was given by the information available at that time, and although not the correct one, may serve a purpose. In the following is an answer I believe is the correct one.

**The short answer**

Most of the images had partly corrupt headers. The reason might be in the original images, conversion from other image formats or in Delphi7, but I couldn't set aside enough time to debug the code. If I had the time I would look at TBitmap.ReadDIB and TBitmap.Changed. The error surfaces in Delphi XE7 (possibly also in earlier version) because some changes have been made in above mentioned methods.

The cure is to *redraw the images in a decent image editor*.

**The longer answer**

I came to the corrupt images conclusion by investigating Glyph.Data of a couple of TBitBtn controls in the .dfm file. Those that seem to be wrong have similar errors in the bitmap headers. Let's look at one of them:

```
ToolButton1: TBitBtn

    Glyph.Data = {
      36340000424D3638000000000000360800002800000040000000400000000100
      1800000000000030000000000000000000000001000000000000724242007B47
      ...}
Glyph.BitmapSize     = 13366
bmfh.bfType          = BM
bmfh.bfSize          = 14390
bmfh.bfReserved1     = 0
bmfh.bfReserved2     = 0
bmfh.bfOffBits       = 2102
bmih.biSize          = 40
bmih.biWidth         = 64
bmih.biHeight        = 64
bmih.biPlanes        = 1
bmih.biBitCount      = 24
bmih.biCompression   = 0
bmih.biSizeImage     = 12288
bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 0
bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 0
bmih.biClrUsed       = 256
bmih.biClrImportant  = 0
```

The structure of the whole Glyph.Data is

```
Glyph.BitmapSize (size  4 bytes), managed by Delphi
BITMAPFILEHEADER (size 14 bytes)
BITMAPINFOHEADER (size 40 bytes)
bmiColors array  (size, when used, should be biClrUsed * SizeOf(TRGBQuad) or 1024 in this case)
bmBits (pixel values, either indexes to bmiColors or direct RGB(A) color values)
```

The problems are:

1. Glypf.BitmapSize is 13366 but `bmpfh.bfSize` reports it to be 14390, a difference of 1024 bytes.
2. Offset of pixel array is reported to be 2102. Subtracting size of bmfh (14) and bmih (40) leaves 2048 bytes for the colortable, bmiColors. Should be 1024.
3. The actual image data in the .dfm is 1024 bytes for the color table, bmiColors. When the image is read in XE7 the erroneous bfOffBits offsets the beginning of the pixel data and thus we see the shift in the image and its colors.
4. When the image is 'reloaded' by opening the image editor the error is repeted with already erroneous data and the image and color shifts are exaggerated.

As said above, the cure is to redraw the images. One could of course also attempt to change the .dfm files directly.

Comment: Is there a free tool to redraw the image quickly ? Thanks.

Comment: @aleroot Not that I know of, but I already corrected the images. Look in the Embarcadero forum for a message to you.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a mismatch between `NumGlyphs` property and actual number of Glyphs in the image.
I can not explain why you don't have the problem in Delphi 7, but I can create the same effect in XE7 with e.g. a 64x64 TBitBtn, a 256 pixel wide image, that has four glyphs (64 pixels wide each), if I set `NumGlyphs := 3`.

In design time, the first glyph is shown. The calculation of pixels per glyph (256 div 3) would give a width of 85 pixels. But that doesn't matter since we are seeing the first glyph, beginning from first pixel.

In runtime it seems the button is in disabled (`Enabled=false`) state, and thus it shows the second glyph, but because of wrong value in NumGlyphs it shows the pixels starting with left 85 forward, thus cutting 21 pixels from left and bleeding those 21 pixels from the third glyph into view.

---

You can compare the beginning of the Glyph.Data in the .dfm files (in D7 and XE7) with the following break up

```
Glyph.Data = {
  36C00000424D36C0000000000000360000002800000000010000400000000100
  18000000000000C00000C40E0000C40E00000000000000000000F0F0F0F0F0F0
  F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0
  ...
```

interpreted as

```
offs  36C00000    file size = 0x0000C036 = 49206
0000  424D        'BM' signature
0002  36C00000    file size
0006  0000        reserved 2 bytes
0008  0000        reserved 2 bytes
000A  36000000    pixel array offset = 0x36 = 54
000E  28000000    BITMAPINFOHEADER size 0x28 = 40
0012  00010000    bitmap width 0x0100 = 256
0016  40000000    bitmap height 0x0040 = 64
001A  0100        num of color planes = 1
001C  1800        num of bits per pixel = 24
001E  00000000    compression method (0 = none)
0022  00C00000    raw bitmap data size 49152 = 256 x 64 x 3 bytes
0026  C40E0000    horizontal resolution (pix per meter) 3780/m
002A  C40E0000    vertical resolution (pix per meter) 3780/m
002E  00000000    num of colors in color palette or 0 for default 2^n
0032  00000000    num of important colors used, or 0 for every color is important
pixel array follows
0036                                                  F0F0F0F0F0F0
003C  F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0
```

Delphi adds its own size in front of the actual .bmp file. Offset is from the 'BM' signature

---

**Edit after additional data**

The three lines that are the same in D7 and XE7 interpreted:

```
Glyph.Data = {
36050000    File size 1334
424D        'BM'
36050000    file size 1334
0000
0000
36040000    1078 pix arr offset
28000000    40 header size
10000000    16 bmp width
10000000    16 bmp height
0100        1 color planes
0800        8 bits per pix
00000000    no compression
00010000    256 raw bitmap data size
00000000    0 horiz pix per meter
00000000    0 vert ppm
00010000    256 colors in palette
00000000    all colors important
00164900001C ....
```

Doesn't really fit the image you posted, which is 64 x 64 within the thin gray border and has 1628 unique colors.

But what really puzzles me is the change when you click the Glyph property. According the diff listing the three first replaced (-) lines don't match the above three lines at all. Break up follows:

```
{
36340000    13366
424D        'BM'
36380000    14390
0000
0000
36080000    2102 pix arr offset
28000000    40 header size
40000000    64 width
40000000    64 height
0100
1800
00000000
00300000    12288 raw bmp data size
00000000
00000000
00010000    256 colors in palette
00000000
724242007B47 ...}
```

Now, this matches the size (64 x 64) but not number of colors. Anyway the rest is corrupt and useless data. Go figure. The only solution I can think of is to replace the image.

Since I already had your posted image in my editor, I made a triple image (normal, disabled, pressed) 192 x 64 and tested in D7 as well as in XE7 and works fine for me.

Here, since your original is lost, as a friendly seasons gift :-)

[image]

Comment: Does this explain the color shift?

Comment: @Sertac No, not as such. SilverWarior is probably right concerning corrupted data, and then that can also cover for the shift in the image. I was hoping OP would have answered S's comment. I will add my own q.

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional information ... Thanks for the help.